# How to replace certain value in the String Using arrays

Tags: java

```
String[] enc=new String[]{"w","e","l","c","o","m"};
    String[] cod=new String[] {"111","10","00","110","010","011"};
    String real="";
    int sindex=0;
    int eindex=1;
    String cdd="111100011001001110";
    StringBuilder code=new StringBuilder(cdd);

    String temp;
    for(int i=0;i<code.length();i++){
        temp=code.substring(sindex, eindex++);
        if(Arrays.asList(cod).contains(temp)){
            int j=Arrays.asList(cod).indexOf(temp);
            int z=code.indexOf(temp);
            StringBuilder y = code.delete(z, z+temp.length());
        temp=y.toString();
        real+=enc[j];
        System.out.println(y);

        }
    }
```

I have these two arrays enc[] and cod[], contains characters and codes respectively what i want to do is just check each value of cod array in cdd string and replace it with its respective String from enc[]...
By running this code i am getting only "w" while the result was suppose to be "welcome".

Comment: Ok, have you made any attempt? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes but it didnt work...

Comment: What *specifically* did you try, and what do you mean by "didn't work?"

Comment: @kiddo If you tried something, **edit** the question and show what you tried, and *explain* in what way it "didnt work", e.g. show error, or show actual vs expected result.

Comment: ok, everyone i have updated the code in question plz check...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - i have refactored yours :)

public class enc {

```
    private static boolean valueFound=false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] enc=new String[]{"w","e","l","c","o","m"};
        String[] cod=new String[] {"111","10","00","110","010","011"};
        String real="";
        int sindex=0;
        int eindex=1;
        String cdd="111100011001001110";

        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < cod.length; i++) {
                if (cdd.startsWith(cod[i])) {
                    real += enc[i];
                    cdd = cdd.substring(cod[i].length());
                    valueFound = true;
                } else {
                    valueFound = false;
                }

            }
        }
        while(valueFound);
        System.out.println(real);

            }
        }
```